# Grouping a dataframe by element and counts in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am starting with a dataframe of the form:

```
scope   provider1    provider2   provider3
------------------------------------------
h1       A             AA          AAA
c12      B             AA          BBB
hn3      A             BB          AAA
hs34     C             CC          BBB
623x     B             DD          CCC
m23      A             AA          BBB
```

where `A`, `AA` and `AAA` are three completely different labels.

I want to count the number of times each label appears and obtain the dataframe:

```
label    provider   value_count
-------------------------------
A        provider1    3
B        provider1    2
C        provider1    1
AA       provider2    3
BB       provider2    1
CC       provider2    1
DD       provider2    1
AAA      provider3    2
BBB      provider3    3
CCC      provider3    1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (df.melt('scope', value_name='label', var_name='provider')
        .groupby(['provider','label'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='value_count')
        )
print (df)
    provider label  value_count
0  provider1     A            3
1  provider1     B            2
2  provider1     C            1
3  provider2    AA            3
4  provider2    BB            1
5  provider2    CC            1
6  provider2    DD            1
7  provider3   AAA            2
8  provider3   BBB            3
9  provider3   CCC            1
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('scope')
        .stack()
        .rename_axis(['scope','provider'])
        .reset_index(name='label')
        .groupby(['provider','label'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='value_count')
)
print (df)
    provider label  value_count
0  provider1     A            3
1  provider1     B            2
2  provider1     C            1
3  provider2    AA            3
4  provider2    BB            1
5  provider2    CC            1
6  provider2    DD            1
7  provider3   AAA            2
8  provider3   BBB            3
9  provider3   CCC            1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
(df.melt(id_vars='scope', value_name='label', var_name='provider')
   .groupby(['variable', 'value']).size().reset_index())
```

---

```
     label provider 0
0  provider1     A  3
1  provider1     B  2
2  provider1     C  1
3  provider2    AA  3
4  provider2    BB  1
5  provider2    CC  1
6  provider2    DD  1
7  provider3   AAA  2
8  provider3   BBB  3
9  provider3   CCC  1
```